# SpringBoot test configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-test

I've started to learn Spring Boot in version 2.1.0 and I made a simple application Controller->Service->Repository->Database(H2). Very, very simple application just to start with Spring Boot.

I've read that in that framework I can add under **src/resources** a file **data.sql** where I can define insert/update etc. and after run my application that data will be stored. Everything works ok, but when I wanted to write test for my service, just to check if my repository works ok (I test DB for learning purpose) I see that while I run my test in my DB there are already values from data.sql, but I don't have data.sql under test folder. It is under src.

Maybe someone knows, how to configure project that not to take this data.sql from src/resources? Is it possible? Maybe I have to add some more annotations?

**** EDIT ****

[This is my repo:](https://github.com/pietrasikk/library-database-service)

Comment: You sure that db exists outside of your app and when you run your test it just takes data from database? Or it is in-memory db? If you dont want to use data from db you should mock your repository

Comment: I use in-memory DB. Why when I run my ServiceTest SpringBoot scan my app structure and even when ServiceTest is under test/<path>/ServiceTest it takes data.sql which is under src/resources?

Comment: And I'm sure that it takes data from my in-memory DB, because in data.sql I have 2 inserts and in my test when I test for example "getAll()" I expect 0 results but I got 2.

Comment: by the way how you use repository in test?

Comment: I link my repo, you can check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create test `application-test.properties` in `test/resources` 
and override in in test like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ExampleApplication.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:test.properties")
public class ExampleApplicationTests {

}
```

Then in you new created `application-test.properties` file block running your script:

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never
```